# how to use lambda functions to data clean excel in python?

Tags: python, arrays, lambda, data-cleaning

I am trying to data clean an excel using Python

the requirement is this:
100 excel files managing amazon inventory, filter feature, getting amazon prime products that are lower and equal to $20 and used by males.

all the excel look something like this:

```
product cost gender prime?
   book    20   male   yes
   pencil  10   female no
   short   15   male   yes
   ...
```

Also, I would like the prime column to be removed in the result.

So, the result would look something like the following:

```
 product cost gender
 book    20   male 
 short   15   male  
 ...
```

I imported the excel using this code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

cwd = os.path.abspath('') 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.XLSX'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True)
```

I done the cleaning process by changing the result to an array list:

```
array = df.to_numpy().tolist()
```

I go the array like so:

```
array = [['comic', 15, 'male', 'yes'], 
         ['paint', 14, 'male', 'no'], 
         ['pen', 5, 'female', 'yes'], 
         ['phone case', 9, 'male', 'yes'], 
         ['headphone', 40, 'male', 'yes'], 
         ['book', 20, 'male', 'yes']]
```

I use the code like this:

```
for line in array:
    for element in line:
        #add action here
```

And got the result like this:

```
array = [['comic', 15, 'male'],
         ['phone case', 9, 'male'], 
         ['book', 20, 'male']]
```

I got the wanted result then export it to the clean data excel

```
result = pd.DataFrame(array)
result.to_excel('clean_data.xlsx')
```

But I hope that the code use apply and lambda function instead to reduce the number of lines but I am not so sure the array strategy is suitable or not.

I am aware that lambda is just a style of coding but this assignment also have the requirement of using lambda function.

It there few lines of lambda code that can do all the requirements?

Can anyone show the Python code to do it ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: there's no reason to use a Python lambda for this .. additionally, is this a `list()` object or numpy array?

Comment: The expected output is missing `['pencil ', 10, 'female']`

Comment: `apply` is not the preferred way of doing things, it is a *last resort*. And using a `lambda` expression or a function created with a function definition statement is a matter of *style*, it has no impact on anything important. This is crucial to understand.

Comment: "I done the cleaning process by changing the result to an array" **no**. You created a *list*. Which sort of makes using pandas pointless. Just *use pandas the way it is meant to be used*, something like `df = df[(df['gender'] =='male') & (df['cost'] <= 20]`

Comment: Don't make such a modification that the previous sense of your question changes drastically. Now, you're showing pandas dataframe, it's much easier to do it with pandas than doing it with the list of lists.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `filter`, and `lambda` together to filter out the sub-lists that don't meet the criteria, then take only the values upto second last item in the sub-list using list comprehension to remove `yes/No` values:

```py
>>> [x[:-1] for x in filter(lambda x: x[1]<=20 and x[-1]=='yes', array)]

[['comic', 20, 'male'], ['pen', 5, 'male'], ['book', 15, 'male'], ['pencil ', 10, 'female']]
```

You can also combine `map` and `filter` with `lambda`:

```py
>>> list(map(lambda x: x[:-1], filter(lambda x: x[1]<=20 and x[-1]=='yes', array)))

[['comic', 20, 'male'], ['pen', 5, 'male'], ['book', 15, 'male'], ['pencil ', 10, 'female']]
```

**UPDATE:**

Since, you have dataframe after updating the question, you can do it with the dataframe, then later convert it to list:

```py
>>> df[(df['cost'].le(20))&df['prime?'].eq('yes')].iloc[:,:-1].values.tolist()

[['comic', 20, 'male'], ['pen', 5, 'male'], ['book', 15, 'male'], ['pencil ', 10, 'female']]
```

Comment: This would be very unpythonic, insteald of `map(..., filter(...))` use a *list comprehension*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I understand that but OP is specifically asking for `lambda`, that's why I supplied this example with the combination of `map` and `filter`

Comment: So what? The OP clearly doesn't know the right way to do things. If someone asks, "how do I shoot myself in the foot", you should explain to them that they shouldn't shoot themselves in the foot

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to use a lambda for this. A list comprehension is the normal "pythonic" way to filter lists.

```
array = [['comic', 20, 'male', 'yes'], 
        ['paint', 14, 'male', 'no'], 
        ['pen', 5, 'male', 'yes'], 
        ['phone case', 9, 'female', 'no'], 
        ['headphone', 40, 'female', 'yes'], 
        ['book', 15, 'male', 'yes'], 
        ['pencil ', 10, 'female', 'yes'],  
        ['shirt', 25, 'male', 'no']]

result = [entry[:3] for entry in array if entry[1] <= 20 
        and entry[2] == "male" and entry[3] == "yes"]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `lambda` + `.apply`, that is *a last resort*, You should be using `pandas` the way it is designed to be used - with vectorized operations. Given:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
  product  cost  gender prime?
0    book    20    male    yes
1  pencil    10  female     no
2   short    15    male    yes
```

Then just something like:

```
In [11]: df[(df['prime?'] == 'yes') & (df['gender'] =='male') & (df['cost'] <= 20)].drop('prime?', axis=1)
Out[11]:
  product  cost gender
0    book    20   male
2   short    15   male
```

An important thing to understand is that using a `lambda` expression if you *were* going to use `.apply` is simply a matter of style, lambda expressions create the exact same sort of function object that a function definition statement does.

Answer (score 1):

Option without useless lambda:
`[x[:-1] for x in array if x[1]<=20 and x[-1]=='yes']`